# SqlConnection manager boilerplate..thing?

Tags: c#

Just 1st student rotating from java to C# here. When we were studying Java we were given this kind of SQL connection manager class thing, which is just basically just bunch of code to make it easier accessing it in different classes (It's written by my danish teacher and has some misspells/inside jokes, not sure):

```
 public class DbConnection
 {   //Constants used to get access to the database
//SQL Server
private static final String  driver = "nope";
//  private static final String  driver = "nope";
private static final String  databaseName = ";databaseName=nope";
//SQL Server
//  private static String  userName = ";user=sa";
private static String  userName = "; user=nope";
private static String password = ";password=nope";


private DatabaseMetaData dma;
private static Connection con;
// an instance of the class is generetated
private static DbConnection  instance = null;

// the constructor is private to ensure that only one object of this class is created
DbConnection()
{
    String url = driver + databaseName + userName + password;

    try{
        //load af driver
        //SQL Server
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("Load af class ok");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Can not find the driver");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }//end catch
    try{
        //connection to the database
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        //set autocommit
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        dma = con.getMetaData(); // get meta data
        System.out.println("Connection to " + dma.getURL());
        System.out.println("Driver " + dma.getDriverName());
        System.out.println("Database product name " + dma.getDatabaseProductName());
    }//end try
    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Problems with the connection to the database");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(url);
    }//end catch
}//end  constructor

//closeDb: closes the connection to the database
public static void closeConnection()
{
    try{
        con.close();
        System.out.println("The connection is closed");
    }
     catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error trying to close the database " +  e.getMessage());
     }
}//end closeDB

//getDBcon: Get-method, returns the connection to the database
public  Connection getDBcon()
{
   return con;
}
//this method is used to get the instance of the connection
public static DbConnection getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
      instance = new DbConnection();
    }
    return instance;
}
public static void startTransaction()
{ try{
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
  catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("fejl start transaction");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
public static void commitTransaction()
{ try{
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
  catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("fejl commit transaction");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
public static void rollbackTransaction()
{ try{
    con.rollback();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
  catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("fejl rollback transaction");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
}//end DbConnection
```

So to get used to C# for second year i thought of first of recreating this in C# and first of all: Is it good idea to have it in C#? I see many people just using

```
 using(SqlConnection....){}
```

thing and I'm not sure how to implement autoCommits/Transaction rollbacks since for example transactions in C# are different classes
So far i made this little class:

```
class DbConnection
{
    private const string DB_USER_ID = "user id=sa;";
    private const string DB_USER_PASSWORD = "password=nope;";
    private const string DB_SERVER_URL = @"server=localhost\SQLExpress1;";
    private const string DB_NAME = "database=test; ";
    private const string DB_TIME_OUT = "connection timeout=30";
    private const string DB_TRUSTED_CONN = "Trusted_Connection=yes;";

    private static SqlConnection myConnection = null;
    private static DbConnection instance = null;

    // private constructor to ensure that only object of this class is created
    private DbConnection()
    {
        createConnection();
    }
    // Instantiates SqlConnection object
    private void createConnection()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to create connectiong...");
        try
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(DB_USER_ID +
                DB_USER_PASSWORD +
                DB_SERVER_URL +
                DB_TRUSTED_CONN +
                DB_NAME +
                DB_TIME_OUT);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problems with the connection to the database");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void openConnection()
    {
        try{
            myConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection succesfful!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem closing connection");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection getDBcon()
    {
        return myConnection;
    }

    public static DbConnection getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DbConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that DbConnection class is bad stuff. Throw it away. In VB the author would have used ON ERROR RESUME NEXT.

Comment: this might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com since you don't have a specific question

Comment: Is your question _"How to implement transactions using an `SqlConnection`"_? That's pretty well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, that DbConnection class is bad stuff. Throw it away. In VB the author would have used ON ERROR RESUME NEXT.

The main problem is that errors are just thrown away. The program continues in a bad state.

Next problem is a static (globally shared) connection object. That's not thread-safe and if the connection ever breaks (network issue) it permanently breaks.

.NET has connection pooling. This class is something you don't need. Maybe you can write yourself a little helper to open a connection:

```
static SqlConnection CreateConnection() {
 ...
}

using (var conn = CreateConnection()) {
}
```

How much more simple can it be?

Comment: Alright, dbConnectio  class is bad, use C# connection pooling, got it, thats what i needed. Thanks

Comment: @user1897229 that DbConnection class is the devil. A good example to learn what not to do.